# Difference in libraries

Tags: compiler-construction, xcode4

When I compile my code using same tool in two different pc's why is there a lot of difference in the library(ie .a lib)generated after compilation as when i make a byte by byte comparison of library i see lot of differences.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a lot more detail about the problem. What compier(s) are you using? What architecture are the two PCs? etc.

Comment: If these are really PCs then why is the question tagged with [objective-c] [ios] and [xcode4]?

Comment: @WillPragnell m using  gcc compiler for my compilation and both pc's are x86 architecure only

Answer (score 2):

The compiler uses not just your source code but also the libraries in your environment libs (version may differ), and also takes your computer specification (architecture, specific CPU, etc.) into account. Plus, you yourself can set additional options in this step.

So it's totally expected that your binaries are totally different.

Read about how a compiler works here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

Comment: @yuji thanks for your reply , but i am having same architecture and compiler.

Comment: Do you have the same exact CPU? The same exact version of all the libraries that are being linked?

Comment: No the cpu is different because i m using a desktop mac pc and a macbook pro laptop , using xcode to generate my libraries but i see that the framework version m using is different in both systems.